# how to find the count of a grep per file in a grep in a regex

Tags: grep

How can I show the count of a grep per file when searching in various files at once via regex

```
grep -c -? somestring log*
```

so, if I have n files log_1, log_2, log_3, .., log_n and I grep -c for somestring, then I would like the output to be

```
log_1 'result of grep -c in file log_1'
log_2 'result of grep -c in file log_2'
```

Can I do this with a grep command or do I have to construct some sort of loop?

Comment: grep -cH <searchString> <files>

Comment: Thanks Almas, that helped a lot. Is there also a way to have it print the file name as well?

Comment: -H will print the file name i.e. <file1>:<count>\n<file2>:<count>. What output you are seeing?

Comment: `grep -c "pattern" files*` is enough. Note, though, that two matches in the same line will count just as one. This is because `grep -c` indicates how many lines contain the pattern. `-H` is the default when you have multiple files, so you don't have to explicit it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wrote -ch instead, which did not print the file names. -cH works great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From almas shaik. works great

```bash
grep -cH <searchString> <files>
```

Comment: `-H` isn't necessary, `grep -c <searchString> <files>` give same output.